# What is the path to an action inside controllers' subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have controllers inside a folder inside the `controllers` folder such that I get this shell result:

```
ls app/controllers
...
users
users_controller.rb
videos_controller.rb
...

ls app/controllers/users
registrations_controller.rb  sessions_controller.rb
```

In `routes.rb`, I have:

```
post 'terms_accept', to: "users/registrations#terms_accept"
```

I don't know how to make the path from a form to an action `terms_accept` inside `registrations_controller`.

Could you give a hand, please?

Comment: Paste the output of `rails routes`.

Comment: Check the given answer by `sa77`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rake routes | grep terms_accept` to get route `prefix` for your `terms_accept` action, when you get the `prefix`, you can use `prefix_path` on your form.

If you want to explicitly define path `prefix` for your action, you can do it with `as` keyword to name your path

```
post '/terms_accept', to: "users/registrations#terms_accept", as: :terms_accept
```

Then, use it in the form: `<%= form_tag terms_accept_path do %>`

Comment: Thanks! Very smart move!

Answer (score 1):

run the `rails routes` command in terminal you will get what is path for ur `terms_accept` action , it should be `user_terms_accept_path`.